# YoutubeのAPIで人気の動画を取得したい

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube

YoutubeAPIで動画を取得したいのですが、
・アップロードしてから特定の期間内（新しい動画を取りたい）
・一定回数以上再生されているもの
を取得することは可能なのでしょうか。